# Translating a 1.8 V FPGA pulse to 24 V pulse to power a solenoid

Tags: transistors, level-shifting

I am designing a board that will interface between a FPGA board and solenoid that powers a pneumatic system.

The signal coming from the FPGA is a LVCMOS 1.8 V signal. Current from the FPGA signal is approximately 10 mA. I desire the output of the designed board to be a 100 mA 24 volts to power the solenoid. My initial thoughts are using a BJT transistor to accomplish this task.

Doing some simple online searching I found this [DIY project](http://www.incrediblediy.com/2013/02/simple-33v5v-level-shifter.html) that is translating 3.3 V to a 5 V signal. I assume I can use this as my basis using BJT transistors, though my knowledge on electrical engineering is limited.

Is this the appropriate approach to take mimicking the DIY project, or is the voltage and current difference too large? If the simple design is okay, how do I go about selecting the correct resistor values and BJT transistors?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have 24V available in the system somewhere else? The link that you posted isn't so much a voltage translation as using your logical output (1.8V, or in the DIY post's case 3.3V) to switch a larger voltage. If this is what you are trying to do, then you should be able to do a similar thing. I wouldn't use BC547's though - their max collector current is 100mA, and you probably want some margin.

Comment: FPGAs are one of the more expensive and delicate circuit components you might end up playing with.  While what you seek *can* be done with a transistor and a diode, consider the extra step of having the FPGA drive an optocoupler via a transistor, and have the output of the optocoupler drive a transistor which drives your relay.   This is not *necessary*, but may be worth the extra effort for the extra protection against implementation issues.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Is this similar to the diagram posted by JRE below? Except it includes the additional optocoupler?

Comment: After the optocoupler, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your life easy.

Don't try to switch the 24Volts.

Switch the solenoid to ground.

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgcmHK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diode is NOT optional.  The 1N4007 is a stand in.  Which diode you really need depends on how much current the solenoid can kick back when you turn it off, and I don't know how much that might be.

Without the diode, the solenoid will build up a high voltage when you turn off the transistor.  This voltage can easily be higher than the voltage rating of the transistor.  That will kill the transistor in short order, so make sure to include the diode.

R1 can be made larger or smaller depending on how much current it takes to fully switch the transistor from 1.8V.

The type of transistor use use for Q1 depends on how much current the solenoid takes to operate.  You must make sure that it is rated for enough current and for at least 24VDC from collector to emitter - more is better.

The 2N3904 is rated for 40V from collector to emitter, but only 200mA.  You will probably need to check the current your solenoid draws.  Depending on that, you will need to find a transistor with the proper ratings.

Comment: Well, he can use NMOS as well. That way things he should care about would be Vgs, Rds, current rating and flyback diode

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! The solenoid only needs 100 mA in order to operate, so it seems like the 2N3904 would be a good option. 

I'll have to take a step back and review some circuit information to fully understand this. Thanks again for your help.